# calling javascript function from vbscript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vbscript, hta

Writing an hta application to load data from a php based web page to oracle form. Need to use sendkeys and its not available in any js framework (not in selenium also). That's the reason I am mixing jquery with vbscript. It's simple but not working

```
<script language="VBScript">
    Function startDataLoad()
        MsgBox ("Starting Data Load")
        DataLoad
    End Function

    Sub DataLoad()
        Dim objShell, WshShell
        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.AppActivate ("Oracle Applications - DEV ")
        Dim dteWait

        Dim dataArray
        dataArray = find_all_selected()

        For Each x In dataArray
        objShell.SendKeys (x)
        If (x = "^s") Then
        dteWait_l = DateAdd("s", 0.03, Now())
        Do Until (Now() > dteWait_l)
        Loop
        End If
        Next

        objShell.SendKeys ("^s")

    End Sub
</script>

<script language="javascript">
    function find_all_selected() {
        var data_loader_a = [];
        $('body').find('input:checked').each(function () {
            current_data = $(this).closest('.parent ').find('li.data_loader_val').data('data_loader').split('|');
            data_loader_a.push(current_data);
        });
        return data_loader_a;
    }
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: remember most of the browser wont support vbscript....

Comment: How did you connect JQuery to your hta? I don't see any definition of `$`. Place the full jquery.min.js code within your hta, or link it using `<script src="...">` tag. BTW, generally usage of `.SendKeys()` is very unreliable, it's the worst method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not working" is not working as a problem description - you need to describe the actual vs. expected behaviour and publish error messages in detail.

If your JScript function is not called at all, or if the SendKeys have no effect, you need to show the code of a simplified but executable .hta.

If all else 'works', but the (J(ava)Script) array returned from the JScript function can't be used in your VBScript code, consider to use a .NET ArrayList as a collection. In (minimalistic) code:

```
<html>
 <head>

  <title>PingPong</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="PingPong"></HTA>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
   Sub Window_onLoad()
     Dim al : Set al = getAL()
     Dim e
     For Each e In al
         MsgBox e
     Next
   End Sub
  </SCRIPT>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript">
   function getAL() {
     var al = new ActiveXObject("System.Collections.ArrayList");
     al.Add("one");
     al.Add("two");
     return al;
   }
  </SCRIPT>

 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

**On second thought:**

Based on info from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xc634c13%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) or [here](http://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/scriptsamples/arrays) I always believed that you can't use JScript arrays in VBScript:

```
There is currently no way to convert a JavaScript array into a VBArray.
```

But having written my test/demo code, I couldn't resist to give it a try once again:

```
<html>
 <head>

  <title>PingPong</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="PingPong"></HTA>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
   Sub Window_onLoad()
     Dim al : Set al = getAL() ' <-- the Set is required
     Dim e
     For Each e In al
         MsgBox e
     Next
     MsgBox TypeName(al)
   ' MsgBox al(0) will fail
   End Sub
  </SCRIPT>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript">
   function getAL() {
/* let's keep it simple
     var al = new ActiveXObject("System.Collections.ArrayList");
     al.Add("one");
     al.Add("two");
*/
     return ["zero", "one", "two"]; // al;
   }
  </SCRIPT>

 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

So obtaining the JScript (literal) array with Set/as an Object makes the collection useable with For Each. As this would mean just one change in your
code:

```
dataArray = find_all_selected()
```

=>

```
Set dataArray = find_all_selected()
```

you may give it a try, despite my admission that I have no clue wrt the WHY it 'works'.

Comment: Hey..Thanks..after reading your post I realized that I am sending a two dimensional array from java script and trying to use it as a one dimensional array in vbscript ...another issue, in vbscript I have not defined it as an array...now I got a working version i.e if I return data_loader_a[0] and use it in vbscript then it works..but struggling if I return the data_loader_a and use two 'for each' look on vbscript

Comment: Marking answer as the concept and two links helped me to get what I want..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

On an HTA application:

To call a Javascript function from a VBScript, use "call":

Sample:

```
<script language="VBScript">
    call find_all_selected()
</script>
```

To call a VBScript Sub from a Javascript:

Sample:

```
<script language="javascript">
    DataLoad();
</script>
```